# router.push not redirect automatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt3

What I want :
Click on a button « Book » and through the url, have the ID name and the price, then redirect to the contact page where the product is. I have to say that it works perfectly except that the redirection to the product page doesn’t happen automatically (more precisely : the url is in the research bar with the info about the product selected and when I reload the page it works well).But i have a error in my console  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: child is null
Here is my code :

```js
 <button @click="reserveProduct" class="flex w-full items-center justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-blue-500 px-8 py-3 text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-blue-400 active:scale-105 transition-all">
Réserver
</button>
```

the script router.push

```js
const reserveProduct = () => {
  router.push({
    name: 'contact',
    query: { productId: product.value.id, productName: product.value.title, productPrice: product.value.price,},
  });
};
```

nuxt.config.ts

```
  router: {
    extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
      routes.push(
        {
          path: '/products/:productId',
          component: '~/pages/[productId].vue',
          name: 'product-details',
          
        },
        {
          path: '/contact',
          name: 'contact',
          component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/contact.vue'),
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown where the error occurs, it's likely caused by parts of the app that you didn't show

Comment: you didn't provide an error message but It seems the product value has not been fetched from the server. when you want to get product.value.id it will give you an error you want to get the id but product.value is undefined. put a console to see product object value before router.push.